# jquery ui datepicker -not displaying all sundays of month

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery-ui datepicker, it is not  displaying  all Sundays in the calender
and I have used the same datepicker in other pages..but it is working perfectly in other pages except this page,...

here is my code.

```
    $(function () {
        $("#startdatebooking").datepicker(
        {
            dateFormat: 'yy, mm , dd',
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonText: "Select date"
        }

        );
    });
    $(function () {
        $("#enddatebooking").datepicker(
        {
            showOn: "both",

            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonText: "Select date"
        });

    });
```

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({ showOn: 'button', buttonImage: "/Content/images/calendar-icon.jpg", buttonImageOnly: true });
```

any help please..!

Comment: Not displaying all Sundays? You mean it's missing all Sundays, or just missing some of them?

Comment: There's nothing in what you've posted that would cause it to leave out anything. Are you sure that's all the code? Can you use the snippet editor to make a working demonstration?

Comment: all Sundays in every month.. this happens only in a particular page..

Comment: Check your CSS, you may be hiding Sundays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say: Check the rendered html with firebug or something alike. Is the html present? Check for the style of the missing nodes etc. Maybe a td:nth-child(6) or something??

Comment: .ui-datepicker-calendar > tbody td td:nth-child(6) {
    background-color: red;
}